# Can you unbind a jQuery function that's bound to the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-binding

I want to prevent this function from working:

```
$(document).on("click",".filters", function(event) {
    $('.filters').removeClass('selectedFilter');
    $(this).addClass('selectedFilter');
    $('.filters div').not('.selectedFilter div').slideUp(200);
    $('.selectedFilter div').animate({opacity:"toggle",height:"toggle"},200);
});
```

I've tried `$(".filters").unbind("click")`, but that's not working, I'm guessing because of how I trigger it in the first place?

Comment: did you tried `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) instead of [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

`$(document).off("click", ".filters");`

From the documentation:

> The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()
>   and Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind()